# Assigning value of hex to char

Tags: c

```
uint8_t a = 0x1234;
```

Will `a == 34`? Is this because `0x34` is the first byte?

If so, how do I perform checks to ensure that the value I assign to `a` does not exceed the size of `uint8_t`?

Comment: There should be a suitable compiler, warning, no? Or is this a question about something like `int x = 0x1234; uint8_t = x;`? (But no, 34 != 0x34.)

Comment: hmm I just stumbled across such behavior, there is no compiler warning though. when i tried running it variable a actually takes the value of 0x34, hence my assumption stated in the post

Comment: So your problem is avoiding overflow in a uint8_t? A uint8_t is just an unsigned integer made up of 8 bytes (typically an unsigned char).

The range of a uint8_t is 0-255 inclusive, so could you not check that the rhs is within that range before assigning the value? e.g.

`int foo = 0x1234;
uint8_t bar = 0;

if (foo >= 0 && foo <= 0xFF)
    bar = foo;`

Sorry if I've totally misunderstood your question :)

Comment: @ChrisParton: 8 bytes -> 8 bits.

Comment: Whoops, my bad! Thanks for picking that up. It's too late for me to edit my post unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> jslagle@AR-E642-45QS3R1:~ $ cat test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  uint8_t a = 0x1234;

  printf("%d %x\n",a,a);
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
jslagle@AR-E642-45QS3R1:~ $ gcc -o test test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:3: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

jslagle@AR-E642-45QS3R1:~ $ ./test
52 34
```

It does indeed behave like that.  GCC gives you a warning if you do it.

Comment: +1 Now, where's a reference to what a C standard has to say ;-)

Comment: The C standard makes this undefined behavior.

Comment: hmm i using visual studio 2010. never gave any warning though.

Comment: @Joshua: It is not undefined behavior.  Unsigned types are modular, assigning out of range values is guaranteed to behave exactly the same way according to the standard (however, the range may differ).

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: my ANSI C book lists overflow being undefined. I admit that most code is written to assume modular, but that is not guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: @Joshua: It is only undefined for signed types like `int`.  If your book states that unsigned overflow is undefined, then the book is wrong.

Comment: Really. I've not known The book by Kerrigan and Ritchie to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, a will take the value of 34? because [34] is the first byte?

Not exactly. If you look at the number in hex format it might look that way. But if you look at the number in decimal, 0x1234 = 4660 (in decimal). Like the sample program given by @user1061077 above, the value stored is `52` which is `4660 % 256` i.e the remainder of the number when divided by `256`. Why `256`? Because in a 8-bit memory you can store only values from 0 through `255` (total `256` numbers). When you assign a value larger than `256`, then the number rolls over and finally the remainder gets stored. So when you try to store `256` instead of `4660`, the resulting value will be `0`. So for larger numbers, the number of times the roll over happens will be exactly the quotient of the division: `number-to-be-stored / total-number-of-numbers`. In your case it is the quotient of `4660/256`.

Comment: The remainder of a value can be calculated with the modulus function (in short mod) 4660 mod 256 = 52 = 0x34. To calculate the modulus of a power of 2 (2,4,8,16,32,64,...) one can instead just use a bit-mask and call the arithmetic-and operator. So instead of calling 4660 mod 256 you also can call 2660 & 256.  When casting from an uint32_t to an uint8_t this is done implicit. All bits from 8 till 32 are zeroed and therefor the statement that 0x34 is the first byte of 0x1234 is more or less correct (depending on how one defines the byte order).

Comment: @LittleFunnyMan: I know what you have explained. I used decimal to explicitly highlight what really happens when you assign a number that is greater than the capacity of the data type.

Comment: I just wanted to say that in your answer it sounded like the computer is actively calculating to cast the value. Arithmetically casting 0x1234 would more likely result in 0xFF (if unsigned).